# Active directory filter to return inactive users

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I have inherited an executable file which updates users in a database table and in Active Directory.

The filter is set to:

```
Dim strFilter As String = "(&(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=" & ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE & ")(whenChanged>=" & Format(dteADLastSyncTime, "yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".OZ))"
```

Which resolves to:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(whenChanged>=20091206100029.OZ))
```

dteADLastSyncTime stores the time where this process was last run and is updated at the end of the program flow.

Now a bug has been found where some inactive users (inactive in the sense that their whenChanged property is >= the last sync time) are not being updated as an inactive user. For found inactive users a flag is meant to be set in the database and in AD.

My question is the strFilter looks off to me, for one it seems like the condition whenChanged>='date' is the wrong way round, but I do not know enough about AD to be sure. Is whenChanged like a last modified flag on the user? If so then shouldn't the condition be whenChanged<='date' ?

Secondly the userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2 - is this not asking Active Directory for already disabled accounts?

Answer (score 0):

The query seems to be looking for accounts that have been disabled since the last time the job ran. I assume that is to make sure it does not process old disabled accounts over and over again.

For example, if the job ran on May 10, then when it runs again on May 11 it would only look for accounts that are disabled *and have been modified after May 10* since you can assume that the job on May 10 already took care of accounts that were modified before May 10.

Now, the accounts that it is not picking up, are they actually disabled?

There are many ways to identify inactive accounts. They can be disabled (which means that someone or some job intentionally disabled the account), they could be expired (which prevents login, but does not set the account as disabled), or they could just be abandoned.

Abandoned accounts can be identified by looking at the last logon dates, or by looking for accounts where the password has been expired for some time.